# CSS resize image off top of screen when window resized larger

Tags: html, css, image

I would like an image at the top of the window from 0px to 500px in height.  It will take up the whole window horizontally and will keep the same aspect ratio at all times.

When the window is resized larger, the bottom of the image will NOT go lower than 500px.  The image will be resized larger off the TOP and RIGHT portions of the screen (to keep the same aspect ratio).  So, the x=0px, y=500px will be fixed location of the bottom left of the image.

The below achieves the correct affect for increasing the image size when the window is horizontally resized, however I don't want the "bottom: 30px;" as this should be in relation to the top of the window. How can this be done?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
*{  
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}

.img99{
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 30px;
}

</style>
<body>


<img class="img99" src="http://a.gifb.in/022014/1392140403_plane_crashes_while_taking_off_on_a_beach.gif" />

</body>
</html>
```

## [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qooufmuf/)

Comment: Try to apply some @media queries css

Comment: change the bottom declaration to top:0px or bottom:0 depending on what you're looking for

Comment: top:0px will NOT make the image resize off the top of the screen.  The image will resize larger downwards which is not what i want.

Comment: Similar to the "airbnb" website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with so many CSS questions, the answer is "use a container div".

I may have misunderstood your requirements, but I was able to get it working whichever way I understood it to be spec'd, so if this isn't quite right, let me know and I'll revise.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        * {  
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #image_limiter {
            top:0;
            width: 100%;
            max-height: 500px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .img99 {
            width: 100%;
        }
      /* 
      924px because of the aspect ratio of the image; 
      it hits full height of 500px when the screen is
      924px wide, so thats when we want to anchor 
      it to the lower left of the container div. 
      */
      @media (min-width: 924px) {
        #image_limiter {
          position: fixed;
          height: 500px;
        }
        .img99 {
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 0px;
          left: 0px;
        }
      }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>

      <div id="image_limiter">
        <img class="img99" src="http://a.gifb.in/022014/1392140403_plane_crashes_while_taking_off_on_a_beach.gif" />  
      </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you, that achieves the resize off the top of the screen.  I made a couple changes to the img99 CSS as I don't want the image to be smaller that 924x500:         .img99 {
            width: 100%;
   min-height: 500px;
   min-width: 924px;
        }

Comment: That was one way I tried as well- in that case, you don't need the media query, and can move those properties up into the main css. Please accept if this solved your problem.